# Linking multiple .asm files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, visual-studio-2017, masm

I use visual studio 2017

Lets say I one assembly file named "Factorial.asm" and I break it into two .asm files named "one.asm" and "two.asm":
Factiorial.asm works just fine.

Factorial.asm contains

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none  

includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
sprintf proto C :vararg
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
MessageBoxA proto :ptr,:ptr,:ptr,:DWORD
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
ExitProcess proto :dword 


.data
   format db "%llu", 13, 10, 0
   _title db "Result",13,10,0

.code

main PROC
    LOCAL szBuf[9]:byte

    mov  eax, 15      ; initial value (low-order bits)
    xor  edx, edx     ; initial value's high-order bits are 0
    mov  ecx, eax     ; loop counter

Factorial:
    dec  ecx          ; decrement counter
    jz   Finished     ; when counter == 0, we're done
    mov  ebx, ecx     ; make copy of counter
    imul ebx, edx     ; high-order bits * multiplier
    mul  ecx          ; low-order bits * multiplier
    add  edx, ebx     ; add high-order product to high-order bits of low-order product
    cmp  ecx, 1
    jg   Factorial    ; keep looping as long as counter > 1

Finished:  
    invoke sprintf, addr szBuf, offset format, eax, edx
    invoke MessageBoxA, 0, addr szBuf, offset _title, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
```

one.asm contains

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none  

includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
sprintf proto C :vararg
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
MessageBoxA proto :ptr,:ptr,:ptr,:DWORD
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
ExitProcess proto :dword 


.data
   format db "%llu", 13, 10, 0
   _title db "Result",13,10,0

.code

main PROC
    LOCAL szBuf[9]:byte

    mov  eax, 15      ; initial value (low-order bits)
    xor  edx, edx     ; initial value's high-order bits are 0
    mov  ecx, eax     ; loop counter

Factorial:
    dec  ecx          ; decrement counter
    jz   Finished     ; when counter == 0, we're done
    mov  ebx, ecx     ; make copy of counter
    imul ebx, edx     ; high-order bits * multiplier
    mul  ecx          ; low-order bits * multiplier
    add  edx, ebx     ; add high-order product to high-order bits of low-order product
    cmp  ecx, 1
    jg   Factorial    ; keep looping as long as counter > 1

main ENDP
```

two.asm contains

```
Finished:  
invoke sprintf, addr szBuf, offset format, eax, edx
invoke MessageBoxA, 0, addr szBuf, offset _title, 0
invoke ExitProcess, 0
```

How would I link "one.asm" and "two.asm" using Visual Studio 2017. Or in other words, call labels from separate .asm files?

Answer (score 1):

There are usually three types of objects that you need to transfer information across files to.

1. Proc defined in *source* file called for in *user* file : By default, in masm, all procs are global. So, the source file needs no declaration, the user file needs a declaration :

   `extern <proc_name> : proc`
2. Variable defined in *source* file and called by a procedure in *user* file : In this situation, the *source* file needs a declaration

   `public <var_name>`
   and the *user* file must contain the declaration :

   `extern <varname> : var_size ; where var_size is word, qword ymmword...`

It is NOT mandatory that the declaration size must match the extern size. However, consequences of not ensuring this match are usually expensive. Also, if a variable has been declared as an extern, and subsequently, not used in that file, it still must match a corresponding public declaration in some file, otherwise linker will fail.

3. Label defined in *source* file and jumped to from a *user* file : identical treatment as a *variable* (case 2) is treated

Trust this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directive *extrn* to declare functions outside of the current source file:

```
        extrn   foo:proc
```

You can optionally use *public* to declare local functions as public, but I think functions are public by default.

Since VS2015, printf is now inlined with C / C++ code, at least in the case of 64 bit builds. One way to deal with this is to have a C / C++ source file that makes a reference to printf, in which case the assembly code can then access printf. I don't know if this applies to sprintf also. You'll get a link error if this is an issue.